# Where can I find keystore sha256 at google play console for assetlinks.json?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have assetlinks.json file in my well-know folder. Where can I find sha256_cert_fingerprints?

```
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.mobile.droid",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "where I can find it in google play console"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

I guess it's the "App signing certificate". Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to the certificate used to sign the apk file.

Answer (score 19):

This changed now, you will find the Signing details under App Integrity[image]

Comment: If you have integrated Firebase phone auth, then this is the way to get the SHA-1 and SHA-256 for your firebase console

Answer (score 9):

**Copy it directly from a signed APK**

> keytool -list -printcert -jarfile YOUR_APP.apk

or check this link for more options
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/android-fingerprint

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use this:

- Google Digital Asset Link Validation Tool → https://goo.gle/3ogC0Ik
- Asset Links Tool Android app → https://goo.gle/3oqWmip

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30023458)